# Matlab как исправить ошибку с функцией внизу?

Tags: matlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция в matlab должна быть в конце файла, но цикл ссылается на результат функции и не работает если функция внизу, как пернести функцию в другой файл и вызвать в цикле? Есть другой выход?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать файл с именем CT.m и переместить туда функцию, если речь идёт об

```
function F=CT(t,x)
```